# Use range as a key value in a dictionary, most efficient way?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, range

I have been wondering if there is some kind of data-structure or clever way to use a dictionary (O(1) lookup) to return a value if there are given values for defined ranges that do not overlap. So far I have been thinking this could be done if the ranges have some constant difference (0-2, 2-4, 4-6, etc.) or a binary-search could be done to do this in O(log(n)) time.

So, for example given a dictionary,

```
d = {[0.0 - 0.1): "a",
     [0.1 - 0.3): "b",
     [0.3 - 0.55): "c",
     [0.55 - 0.7): "d",
     [0.7 - 1.0): "e"}
```

it should return,

```
d[0.05] 
>>> "a"
d[0.8]
>>> "e"
d[0.9]
>>> "e"
d[random.random()] # this should also work
```

Is there anyway to achieve something like this? Thanks for any responses or answers on this.

Comment: Yes, since your ranges are arbitrary anyways you can write a function that maps ranges to integers. Then simply lookup that integer in a list (if number of ranges are fixed), or a dictionary. If the ranges were more systematic the function can be even be a simple lambda function.

Comment: I'm assuming that this solution requires some kind of search to check if the value is within the range, so is at least O(log(n)) in that case? This is fine, I was just wondering if there was some conventional method or data-structure to do it in O(1) time

Comment: This is actually a really interesting question btw. I've never read about hash functions which map contiguous ranges of values to the same index and is probably a really good research problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can have O(1) lookup time if you accept a low(er) resolution of range boundaries and sacrifice memory for lookup speed.

A dictionary can do a lookup in O(1) average time because there is a simple arithmetic relationship between key and location in a fixed-size data structure (`hash(key) % tablesize`, for the average case). Your ranges are effectively of a *variable size* with floating-point boundaries, so there is no fixed tablesize to map a search value to.

Unless, that is, you limit the absolute lower and upper boundaries of the ranges, and let range boundaries fall on a fixed step size. Your example uses values from 0.0 through to 1.0, and the ranges can be quantized to 0.05 steps. That can be turned into a fixed table:

```
import math
from collections import MutableMapping

# empty slot marker
_EMPTY = object()

class RangeMap(MutableMapping):
    """Map points to values, and find values for points in O(1) constant time

    The map requires a fixed minimum lower and maximum upper bound for
    the ranges. Range boundaries are quantized to a fixed step size. Gaps
    are permitted, when setting overlapping ranges last range set wins.

    """
    def __init__(self, map=None, lower=0.0, upper=1.0, step=0.05):
        self._mag = 10 ** -round(math.log10(step) - 1)  # shift to integers
        self._lower, self._upper = round(lower * self._mag), round(upper * self._mag)
        self._step = round(step * self._mag)
        self._steps = (self._upper - self._lower) // self._step
        self._table = [_EMPTY] * self._steps
        self._len = 0
        if map is not None:
            self.update(map)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._len

    def _map_range(self, r):
        low, high = r
        start = round(low * self._mag) // self._step
        stop = round(high * self._mag) // self._step
        if not self._lower <= start < stop <= self._upper:
            raise IndexError('Range outside of map boundaries')
        return range(start - self._lower, stop - self._lower)

    def __setitem__(self, r, value):
        for i in self._map_range(r):
            self._len += int(self._table[i] is _EMPTY)
            self._table[i] = value

    def __delitem__(self, r):
        for i in self._map_range(r):
            self._len -= int(self._table[i] is not _EMPTY)
            self._table[i] = _EMPTY

    def _point_to_index(self, point):
        point = round(point * self._mag)
        if not self._lower <= point <= self._upper:
            raise IndexError('Point outside of map boundaries')
        return (point - self._lower) // self._step

    def __getitem__(self, point_or_range):
        if isinstance(point_or_range, tuple):
            low, high = point_or_range
            r = self._map_range(point_or_range)
            # all points in the range must point to the same value
            value = self._table[r[0]]
            if value is _EMPTY or any(self._table[i] != value for i in r):
                raise IndexError('Not a range for a single value')
        else:
            value = self._table[self._point_to_index(point_or_range)]
            if value is _EMPTY:
                raise IndexError('Point not in map')
        return value

    def __iter__(self):
        low = None
        value = _EMPTY
        for i, v in enumerate(self._table):
            pos = (self._lower + (i * self._step)) / self._mag
            if v is _EMPTY:
                if low is not None:
                    yield (low, pos)
                    low = None
            elif v != value:
                if low is not None:
                    yield (low, pos)
                low = pos
                value = v
        if low is not None:
            yield (low, self._upper / self._mag)
```

The above implements the full mapping interface, and accepts both points and ranges (as a tuple modelling a `[start, stop)` interval) when indexing or testing for containment (supporting ranges made it easier to reuse the default keys, values and items dictionary view implementations, which all work from the `__iter__` implementation).

Demo:

```
>>> d = RangeMap({
...     (0.0, 0.1): "a",
...     (0.1, 0.3): "b",
...     (0.3, 0.55): "c",
...     (0.55, 0.7): "d",
...     (0.7, 1.0): "e",
... })
>>> print(*d.items(), sep='\n')
((0.0, 0.1), 'a')
((0.1, 0.3), 'b')
((0.3, 0.55), 'c')
((0.55, 0.7), 'd')
((0.7, 1.0), 'e')
>>> d[0.05]
'a'
>>> d[0.8]
'e'
>>> d[0.9]
'e'
>>> import random
>>> d[random.random()]
'c'
>>> d[random.random()]
'a'
```

If you *can't* limit the step size and boundaries so readily, then your next best option is to use some kind of [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm); you keep the ranges in sorted order and pick a point in the middle of the data structure; based on your search key being higher or lower than that mid point you continue the search in either half of the data structure until you find a match.

If your ranges cover the full interval from lowest to highest boundary, then you can use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for this; just store either the lower or upper boundaries of each range in one list, the corresponding values in another, and use bisection to map a position in the first list to a result in the second.

If your ranges have *gaps*, then you either need to keep a third list with the other boundary and first validate that the point falls in the range, or use an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). For non-overlapping ranges a simple binary tree would do, but there are more specialised implementations that support overlapping ranges too. There is a [`intervaltree` project](https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/) on PyPI that supports full interval tree operations.

A `bisect`-based mapping that matches behaviour to the fixed-table implementation would look like:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from collections.abc import MutableMapping


class RangeBisection(MutableMapping):
    """Map ranges to values

    Lookups are done in O(logN) time. There are no limits set on the upper or
    lower bounds of the ranges, but ranges must not overlap.

    """
    def __init__(self, map=None):
        self._upper = []
        self._lower = []
        self._values = []
        if map is not None:
            self.update(map)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._values)

    def __getitem__(self, point_or_range):
        if isinstance(point_or_range, tuple):
            low, high = point_or_range
            i = bisect_left(self._upper, high)
            point = low
        else:
            point = point_or_range
            i = bisect_left(self._upper, point)
        if i >= len(self._values) or self._lower[i] > point:
            raise IndexError(point_or_range)
        return self._values[i]

    def __setitem__(self, r, value):
        lower, upper = r
        i = bisect_left(self._upper, upper)
        if i < len(self._values) and self._lower[i] < upper:
            raise IndexError('No overlaps permitted')
        self._upper.insert(i, upper)
        self._lower.insert(i, lower)
        self._values.insert(i, value)

    def __delitem__(self, r):
        lower, upper = r
        i = bisect_left(self._upper, upper)
        if self._upper[i] != upper or self._lower[i] != lower:
            raise IndexError('Range not in map')
        del self._upper[i]
        del self._lower[i]
        del self._values[i]

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from zip(self._lower, self._upper)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, split your data into two arrays:

```
limits = [0.1, 0.3, 0.55, 0.7, 1.0]
values = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

`limits` is sorted, so you can do [binary search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) in it:

```
import bisect

def value_at(n):
    index = bisect.bisect_left(limits, n)
    return values[index]
```

Comment: While this answerr solves the problem stated by the OP, it does not use the `dict` in any way, though. So, as an answer it only partially covers the question asked.

Comment: @JohanL: If you have a better solution please post it.  The question title asks for the "most efficient way."

Comment: I don't. I would be interested in seeing if there is one, though.

Comment: @JohanL sometimes the answer is: don't use a dict. Not often something I say in python...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, yes, I would consider that a valid answer. Questions like this one arises every once in a while, in situations more or less similar to this, and then it is nice to also see it stated: **Don't do that** :-)